# Не могу сделать компиляцию кошельков dash форка

Tags: debian, github

Делаю форк DASH'а  по гайду. Сам форк тут: https://github.com/freelion93/mtucicoin

застрял на последнем этапе. Не хочет компилировать файлы кошельков, выводит следующее

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

то есть, подключается он нормально к github, но идет почему-то по адресу `/mtucicoin/mtucicoin`, а не `freelion93/mtucicoin`.

что делать?

Comment: Вставьте код ошибки в тело вопроса в виде текста, а не изображения (чтобы внести изменения используйте ссылку «[edit]»).

Comment: сообщение об ошибке разработчику уже отправили?